# How to limit string length in firebase

Tags: string, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I working in a firebase database. I need to limit the length of a string field. How do I do that?

The path to the field is:

Col1/doc1/*/*/description

That is, starting with the collection col1, then into doc1, then for all collections under doc1, and all documents under that collection, the description field needs to be limited to 100 characters.

Can someone please explain to me how to do this? Thanks

Comment: well.. if you limit it to 100 character from the db.. you will loose the rest of it. Why don't you do the validation from the client side ?

Comment: From your description I think you're using Cloud Firestore. Is that correct?

Comment: Christophe, it seems like I'll just have to do that (client side programming). Frank, yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 17):

I tried to get the validation from the other answer to work but was unsuccessful. Firestore just doesn't like checking .length on resource data values.

I searched around and this article helped me:
https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-rules-recipes/

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /posts/{postId} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write: if request.auth != null 
                     && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.uid
                     && request.resource.data.body.size() > 0
                     && request.resource.data.body.size() < 255
                     && request.resource.data.title.size() > 0
                     && request.resource.data.title.size() < 255;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For Cloud Firestore you can *validate* that the `description` field is no longer than 100 characters with:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /col1/doc1 {
      allow write: if resource.data.description.size() <= 100;

        match /subcollection1/{doc=**} {
          allow  write: if resource.data.description.size() <= 100;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This applies to `col1/doc` and all documents in `subcollection1`. Note that these rules will not limit the length of the description, since security rules cannot modify the data that is written. Instead the rules reject writes where the description is longer than 100 characters.

There is no way (that I know of) to apply rules to *each* subcollection of only one document. The closest I know is to apply it to all documents and their subcollections:

```
match /col1/(document=**} {
  allow write: if resource.data.description.size() <= 100;
}
```

This applies the validation to all documents in `col1` and in all subcollections under that.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Unfortunately, I am going to have to apply this rule to all collections under doc1, but NOT all documents under col1. Christophe's comment above about imposing this limit on the client side seems like my best bet. But your post is very useful to me anyway as I'm learning about firebase and how to set rules. Thanks.

Comment: You should always combine client-side and server-side validation. If you only do what Christophe proposed, nothing stops your users from calling the Firestore API directly and writing longer data to documents. If you only do mine, the user has a lousy experience, because their writes just get rejected. Do both and you're both secure, and have a good user experience.

Comment: according to the firestore API doco here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#size
we need to use size() instead of length:
resource.data.description.size() <= 100

Answer (score 0):

On the Firebase documentation, for Firestore specifically, it seems that you can use the Map interface's get() function.

For example:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read: if true;
            allow write: if request.resource.data.get('description', '').size() < 256;
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation as of Feb 2023 can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map#get)